# Jquery UI Spinner 'Not a function'

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am hoping someone can help me as all of the posts I have read seem to indicate that the spinner was not released until 1.9, which I am using. I am getting an error that the .spinner is not a function. Here is my code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $( "#ingAmount" ).spinner();
    });
</script>
```

and this is my input:

```
<input id="ingAmount" />
```

I have used the jquery UI library for the slider which works perfectly, so I am not sure why it can't access the spinner.

Thanks!

Comment: is there another version of jQUeryUI being loaded in page somewhere else?

Comment: It's not a customized version that I know of... these are the same links that the Jquery UI folks have on their demo page here: http://api.jqueryui.com/spinner/ (at the bottom). This is the only version I am calling.

Comment: Seems to work ok here: http://jsfiddle.net/xhkdm/

Comment: That's why I am so confused. :/

Comment: ah, I think I know what the problem is. I have the ajax toolkit installed which does in fact reference the older jquery files. :/ Just have to figureout how to make it reference the new ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured this out. I had used NuGet in visual studio to install the AJAX Toolkit... when I did this it installed an old version of Jquery UI which did not have the spinner. Even though I was using the correct scripts on my page it was still accessing the older one. I used NuGet to update the jquery and jquery libraries which in turn updated the one that AJAX was associated with.

(I feel so silly...)